# Vertical align applies to element applied on or other inline-block elements?

Tags: css

hey guys i was just playing around with some CSS , i am new to CSS , i made the following simple demo ::

HTML ::

```
     <label for="test">Name</label>
     <input type="text" id="test">
```

CSS ::

```
                  input {
                height: 70px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                display: inline-block;
                //vertical-align: middle;
            }
```

now the label "looks" perfectly vertically aligned to the input , i guess thats because the default vertical align for display:inline-block is `baseline` , now one interesting point here is when i add vertical-align:middle to the input and go to the browser and open ispector and take off the `vertical align:middle` from the input(temporarly) , the label moves instead of the input , which brings me to my question .

When i add  vertical-align: middle; to input , am i say :

> "Hey Input vertically align urself in the middle with respect to your
>   siblings" **OR**
>
> am i saying to inputs siblings(in this case label) "hey guys !
>   vertically align urselfs in the middle with respect to input" ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

`vertical-align` refer to the alignment of the element to the baseline of the **parent** element for inline elements.

So that's why it's important to ensure that the sibling children all have the same `vertical-align` value is you want them to be consistently aligned to each other.

[**@MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

> Most of the values vertically align the element relative to its parent element:
>
> EG: **middle**
>
> Aligns the middle of the element with the **baseline** of its parent.

[**W3C Reference**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)

Comment: new to css i don't really know what or how baseline functions , is this baseline article here http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/ , i am reading about the , same base line that your talking about ?

Comment: Yep, that's the one. See if this helps - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/5cfov1b9/2/

Comment: last question , is the line-height just for exagerartion ? .... apart from that SUPER-BIG-TANK-YOU :D